# Fill a C# DataTable "on disk" rather than "in memory" to avoid Memory overflow

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to fill two `DataTable` from two different databases for some comparisons and read-only operations. That takes me to `"select *"` into these two `DataTable`.

However, the table I need to retrieve contains about 3 million rows in both databases. I get an `OutOfMemoryException`while filling.

Is there a possibility to have these `DataTable` on disk rather than in memory?
Do you see any other solution to compare/perform read-only on such two huge sets? The things that I need to do make it very complicated to proceed by batches of subsets of rows.

Comment: Do you need the entire row sets in memory to start your comparisons? If not, can you batch them up a do 100k or whatever at a time instead?

Comment: I need the whole set accessible to match keys between DataTable objects.

Comment: I think we need a bit more to go on here if anyone is to give a useful answer. You've not indicated what operations you're performing - someone may be able to suggest a good algorithm that can be easily batched. You don't indicate the DB server - could the operations be done in SQL if the server supports cross-server queries. Nor do you indicate what you're doing once you've done your operations - perhaps you can shrink the "select *" to only the column set you really need?

Comment: "I need the whole set accessible to match keys between DataTable objects" - why?  Can't you read batches from both tables for the same range of key values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the ideal/efficient way of performing this would be to do it within the database.  Unfortunately, your two tables are in two separate databases, which may cause complications.

Are these tables in two different databases on the same server (as in SQL Server instance), or are they in two separate servers?  If they are within the same server/instance, then you could probably perform your comparison logic on the database server.

Otherwise, if these tables are on separate servers, then is there any possibility of setting up some kind of replication between databases so that you can get both data sets into a single database where you can perform your comparisons?

Comment: Unfortunately, one is MSSQL, the other one is SYBASE. I need to look into this replication thing maybe, I have no clue on that topic

Comment: @J.G Sorry I couldn't be more help. Replication is not really my area of knowledge either, but it seems like it is probably the right approach. You may have found this already, but I noticed this guide from Sybase on [setting up replication between ASE and MSSQL](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1024758).

Answer (score 1):

What about sorting both of them by key.

i.e.

```
set1    A  A  A  B  C            E
                 |            
set2             B       D
```

then you can go on set1, change to set2, go back to set1... makes iterating much easier.